# How to move non HDFS HA to HDFS HA

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have HDFS instance which is in standalone mode (no HA). There is about 1.4 TB of data.

As data is growing and it's on single point of failure, we want to move this to High Availability.

To do so what I did is

- Stop existing cluster (namenode & datanode)
- Setup journal nodes (count 3)
- Setup HDFS with HA configuration (on same VM where non HA was present)
- Start HDFS namenode

But seems this is not working out. Everytime am getting heap memory issue. I tried with 16 GB but still no luck.

Below is the error am getting
[image]

Am I missing some step? Or do we need to perform this action differently?

Also a point - we dont have enough disk to setup another HDFS HA and then move data from old node to new.

Comment: Getting heap issues where?  Which server?

Comment: On namenode server. Am not starting any of data node server till namenode comes up.

Comment: Can you send the logs? Which daemon is failing with Heap issue?

Comment: Do you know what the previous heap setting was for the NameNode?  16GB is pretty small for a production NN.

Comment: As per memory req. based on data present, 16 GB is way too high. Ideally for 5-10 million data, 6 GB is more than enough.